# HTTPClient - Submit inputs

Tags: java, http, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

I'm trying to code a small app that will let me track my packages automatically by accessing the local post office site.

The problem I'm encountering is that whenever I do an HttpGet, I don't get the site completely, as it seems some portions are Javascript.

Here's the site:

http://www.correoargentino.com.ar/seguimiento_envios/oidn

If you do an HttpGet of it, you won't be getting the Captcha stuff that comes up on the browser. So my question is, is there any way to get this information with HTTPClient? Or is it impossible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The httpGet capture only the HTML, as you were acessing this by browser, more the javascript code its not executed, you can try get the HTML and create one HTML page and test this. If files css and javascript are with relative path, you can add context for they.

Ex: /css/all.css

Add context: http://www.correoargentino.com.ar/seguimiento_envios/css/all.css

Comment: I'm sorry, I only understood half of your answer. I understand that I'm only getting the HTML with the get method, but how are you suggesting I get the rest? Thanks!

Comment: You can't get the rest, more you can analize the returned html and check the javascript and css urls and set up automatically the page html with the correct url. If the captcha is generate by javascript, you can't get this automatically only with http-client